# Burger menu is preventing scrolling fucntionality?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation, hamburger-menu

I'm creating a *burger menu*, with an *animated drop-down or overlay*, as part of the header for my website. Let's call it ***"mobile-header"-page***.

***Link to the website*** (funnily doesnt execute the function on desktop browser, but works fine when tested on the mobile phone):

https://andreasvoldmaa2.cargo.site/

However, since the drop-down menu need to fill the *entire height of the viewport to display the entire menu* - it means the header fills the entire height of the viewport as well, because it's all *nested* into "one"... this in turn, is preventing proper scrolling functionality (as you're likely to start dragging the ***"mobile-header"-page*** instead, in an attempt to scroll down the page).

I'm not really well-versed in coding or scripting - but there has to be a way to ensure the header is *not interfering* with the scrolling functionality of the page as a whole, while still making sure it has enough *"height"* to expand into the menu?

It's *based* on this, from CodePen: https://codepen.io/312_JohnC/pen/KVrjMa

I'm using ***Cargo 3***.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="window">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <img src="" style="height:30px; margin:10px 70px 0px; position:relative; float:right;">   
    <div class="icon icon-apple"></div>
&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<ul class="menu">
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="shop icon icon-bag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">&nbsp;
 &nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:200);

.window {
    background: linear-gradient(white, rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    position: sticky;
    display: block;
    width: 360px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 65px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: -9999999;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.window .header {
    position: sticky;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.window .header .burger-container {
    position: sticky;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.window .header .burger-container #burger {
    width: 18px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: -4px auto 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    background: #000000;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
    transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}

.window .header .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.window .header .icon.icon-bag {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0.65s;
}

.window .header ul.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 48px 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003456;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.49s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.42s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.28s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.21s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.14s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.07s;
}

.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 2.35;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 100%;
}

.window .header.menu-opened {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #002555;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
    transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}

.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
    transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.27s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.34s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.41s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.48s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.55s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.62s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.69s;
}

.window .header.menu-opened .icon.icon-bag {
    transform: translateX(75px);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.window .content {
    font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
    padding: 67px 4% 0;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: scroll;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.window .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.window .content h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.window .content img {
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 75px auto 75px;
}

.window .content img:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin: 75px auto;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .window {
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .window .header {
        position: absolute;
    }
}

[id="J2926239532"].page {
    min-height: var(--viewport-height);
    justify-content: center;
}

[id="J2926239532"] .page-content {
    padding: 0rem;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

***Javascript (within my "global"-HTML file):***

```
<script>
// Function to toggle menu-opened class
function toggleMenu() {
    var header = document.querySelector('.header');
    if (header) {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    } else {
        console.error("Could not find header element.");
    }
}

// Add event listener to toggle menu when burger icon is clicked
function setupMenu() {
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container');
    if (burger) {
        burger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
    } else {
        console.error("Could not find burger element.");
    }
}

// Add event listener to menu items to close menu when clicked
function setupMenuItems() {
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
    if (menuItems.length > 0) {
        menuItems.forEach(function(item) {
            item.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
        });
    } else {
        console.error("No menu items found.");
    }
}

// Execute script when the entire page has finished loading
window.onload = function() {
    setupMenu();
    setupMenuItems();
};
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Now, I've tried playing with having the header reduced to 10vh when it isn't *"activated"* and then expand to 100vh once activated - but this sort of shifted where to click the burger menu, and definitely disturbed the functionality.

Cargo is also a bit difficult to work with Javascript in, but I've found that ***the Javascript i posted here works when deployed from Cargo***, however the original Javascript from Codepen, didn't work - but works in the website-editor of Cargo 3.

Comment: The only thing that can stop another script from running is a conflict in your code

Comment: Sorry, the first post was done with me on the mobile phone. Are you getting any error messages in the console?